# AJAX function is called first even before first line of jQuery button click, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am working on MVC application where I have to hide button on button click and show when ajax request completed. But the button is hiding after all request is completed. Below is what I have tried.

```
<input type="button" id="btnCalculateAndSave" value="Calculate & Save" style="float: right" />
```

Below is the jQuery click even which has also ajax function calling on same button click.

```
$("#btnCalculateAndSave").on("click", function (e) {
  $("#btnCalculateAndSave").hide();

  //Several lines for validation

  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("myControllerFunction", "myController")',
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: { 
      "p1": v1, 
      "p2": v2
    },
    success: function(result) {
    }  
  }
}
});
```

As I have to prevent multiple time button click event. So button is hiding but after all process of ajax is happened even button hide code is in the first line of jQuery click event.

Comment: I don't see any code that tell the button to be visible again. would it not be `success: function (result) { $("#btnCalculateAndSave").show()} `

Comment: add $("#btnCalculateAndSave").show(); inside success

Comment: I have written show after all process but before ajax call button is not hiding.

Comment: Firstly, where do you call `show()` from? Secondly, remove `async: false` as it's very bad practivce.

Comment: Yes you forgot to put `$("#btnCalculateAndSave").show()`. I think you should put `complete: function(result) {$("#btnCalculateAndSave").show()}`. This will show the button once your ajax request has completed.

Comment: Maybe you need a callback strategy, ajax call should only fire when button is hidden. You can then show the button in success callback of the ajax call.

Comment: The concern is not how to show button rather I am in trouble why it is not hiding before ajax function call as it is in the last but hide is even at first line which work at last aft all process done.

Comment: @SurajKumar Well you code would for sure hide it, `$(this).hide()`. Btw I assume you only have 1 element with this id.

Comment: It is hiding but after several lines of code including validation and ajax function call. I want to restrict multiple times click by hiding the button.

Comment: @SurajKumar why dont you just disable the button then?

Comment: That also doesn't work at start as I want functionality like please wait ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly write main code inside hide function.

```
$("#btnCalculateAndSave").hide(function(){ /* Main Code */ });
```

Below is your main code.

```
 $("#btnCalculateAndSave").on("click", function (e) {
      $("#btnCalculateAndSave").hide(function(){

 $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("myControllerFunction", "myController")',
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: { 
      "p1": v1, 
      "p2": v2
    },
    success: function(result) {
    }  
  }
});

});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps,

```
    var pr;
    $("#btnCalculateAndSave").on("click", function (e) {
              var btn = $(this)
              btn.hide()   

             if(pr)
                 pr.abort() //Prevent multiple time click

            //Several lines for validation
            pr =    $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("myControllerFunction", "myController")',
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: { 
              "p1": v1, 
              "p2": v2
            },
            success: function(result) {
                     btn.show()
            }  
          }
        }
    });
```

Comment: if hide is nit working use btn.css('cssText','display:none !important') ,might be a css issue i guess

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
$("#btnCalculateAndSave").on("click", function (e) {
    $("#btnCalculateAndSave").hide(0, ajaxCall);
    //.....
    //Several lines for validation
    //.....

});

function ajaxCall() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("myControllerFunction", "myController")',
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: { "p1": v1, "p2": v2 },
        success: function (result) {
            //Add this line
            $("#btnCalculateAndSave").show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: My problem is button is hiding after all below code executions. But your answer is how to show button after hide? Not my requirements.

Comment: This will first hide the button and then initiate the ajax call as a call back. The button will be show only after the request is complete. I think this is what you were trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You hide the button first on the click by  `$("#btnCalculateAndSave").hide();`, but there's no instruction for removing the button afterwords.

As per your question, you need to show the button after ajax call is completed. So what you can do is, put code to display the button in ajax success

```
$("#btnCalculateAndSave").on("click", function (e) {
   $("#btnCalculateAndSave").hide();
   .....
   //Several lines for validation
   .....
   $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("myControllerFunction", "myController")',
                    type: "GET",
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    data: { "p1": v1, "p2": v2},
                    success: function (result) { 
//Add this line
$("#btnCalculateAndSave").show();  

                            }  
                        }
                    }
            });
```

Comment: You can also pass a callback function like this: element.hide({done: some_function}); so that the code executes after the button is hidden.

Comment: Request you to please see my comments.

Comment: try if you can hide it before the click, or check if some other css is overriding the display:none set by jquery hide(), or try $("#btnCalculateAndSave").css("display", "none !important":);

Comment: @UsmanAfzal There would be no reason to do that in the current example from the OP

Comment: How to implement call back as in your comment?